# Converting xml file differences to a graph visualization

Tags: r, list, compare, render

I have two lists with structure and would like to render structural differences as a hierarchy or graph and also value differences in elements with identical structure if there is a  difference in values.
Do I need to flatten both lists and compare element by element and then use relist with the element by element differences to create a structured list of differences to send to a rendering package? Or is there a shortcut? 
I am interested in rendering structure that is not common between the two lists and also common structure where there are value differences. 
Code so far

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
f1="sample1.xml"
f2="sample2.xml"
skel1=xmlToList(f1,simplify=TRUE)
skel2=xmlToList(f2,simplify=TRUE)
unlistf1=unlist(skel1)
unlistf2=unlist(skel2)
f1NOTf2=!((unlistf1) %in% (unlistf2)) #value and structure differnce combined
f2NOTf1=!((unlistf2) %in% (unlistf1))
strf1NOTf2=!(names(unlistf1) %in% names(unlistf2)) # structural difference only
strf2NOTf1=!(names(unlistf2) %in% names(unlistf1))
listf1NOTf2=relist(f1NOTf2,skel1)
listf2NOTf1=relist(f2NOTf1,skel2)
strlistf1NOTf2=relist(strf1NOTf2,skel1)
strlistf2NOTf1=relist(strf2NOTf1,skel2)
```

## sample1.xml and sample2.xml below

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country xmlns="http://auto.org/schema/r4.0" name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>-1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
 <mountain name = "Himalaya"/> 
    <country name="Singapore">
  <size name="small" />
  <Temp>Hot</Temp>
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2015</year>
        <gdppc>69900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
 <country name="Japan">
 </country>
</data>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100 </gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapora" color="Green">
        <rank>40</rank>
        <gdppc>59900<free>TRUE</free></gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
  <year>2011</year>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>100</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Comment: What language are you working in, and what does your code look like at present?

Comment: I am using English language but I don't see that it would matter for a comparison problem. I have two very large xml files that I am trying to compare. My code so far

Comment: library(XML)
  library(plyr)
  f1="sample1.xml"
  f2="sample2.xml"
  skel1=xmlToList(f1,simplify=TRUE)
  skel2=xmlToList(f2,simplify=TRUE)
  unlistf1=unlist(skel1)
  unlistf2=unlist(skel2)
  f1NOTf2=!((unlistf1) %in% (unlistf2)) 
  f2NOTf1=!((unlistf2) %in% (unlistf1))
  strf1NOTf2=!(names(unlistf1) %in% names(unlistf2)) 
  strf2NOTf1=!(names(unlistf2) %in% names(unlistf1))
  listf1NOTf2=relist(f1NOTf2,skel1)
  listf2NOTf1=relist(f2NOTf1,skel2)
  strlistf1NOTf2=!(names(unlistf1) %in% names(unlistf2))
  strlistf2NOTf1=!(names(unlistf2) %in% names(unlistf1))

Comment: I did mean programming language.  Also the code should be made part of the question, not as a comment and marked up as code.

Comment: I would like to graph/plot hierarchy of skel1 with listf1NOTf2. listf1NOTf2 tells the differences I am interested in viewing and similarly for skel2. Similarly structural difference of visualization interest would be given by strlistf1NOTf2.

Comment: Dragonthoughts , thanks for your patience. I am using this for the first time and trying to figure out how to post the code and a couple of sample xmls. Language I am using is R.

Comment: Now I realize that listf1NOTf2 etc. needs to be compared recursively under the parent node instead of across all as in my current code.